# Installing NVIDIA driver on Kubuntu 15.04 causes a bad screen resolution

Tags: nvidia, resolution, screen, 15.04, nouveau

I have a fresh install of Kubuntu 15.04. Before installing 15.04 I used Ubuntu 14.10 with the latest NVIDIA drivers. With that version I had no problems with the graphic card (screen resolution).
Btw. my PC contains a GeForce (GF104) GTX 460.

As far as I know the default installation of Kubuntu uses the NOUVEAU driver.
I selected the driver 346.59 provided in System Settings -> Driver Manager to switch to NVIDIA. (I even tried the older versions)

After a reboot I had a very bad screen resolution.
I checked the settings inside "NVIDIA X Server Settings".
There I have seen that the current resolution is: 1920 x 1080, which was not correct. The resolution looked like 640x480 or sth. like that.

Even the "Display Configuration" of Kubuntu showed me that value.
I tried to blacklist NOUVEAU but it didn't change anything.
Even the "boot screen" of Kubuntu disappeared after switching to NVIDIA.

So what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Update:
This is what I get after booting with NVIDIA driver.

```
dmesg | grep nvidia
[    6.700837] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[    6.714403] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel
[    6.719445] [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20140818 for 0000:03:00.0 on minor 0
```

Comment: How about after `sudo dkms autoinstall`?

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem!
First I removed the existing NOUVEAU.

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
```

With `sudo nvidia-xconfig` I created a new `xorg.conf`

After that I added the DPI line.

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
    Option         "DPI" "86 x 86"
EndSection
```

Comment: I have the nvidia driver and not nouveau. But bbswitch seems to be causing the problem when I see the output of dmesg.

Comment: My above solution fixed the bad resolution / bad DPI setting. The above messages still appears in dmesg.

Comment: Does the mouse pointer and system still freeze for a few seconds every 5 to 10 seconds while using it?

Comment: There is no monitor section in the xorg.conf that was created by my nvidia-xconfig.